# Установка свойств в CSS, значения которых не противоречат друг другу

Tags: html, css

Почему если после установки значения свойству `background-color` установить универсальное свойство `background`, значения которых не противоречат друг другу, то свойство `background-color` перестает работать?

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что свойство **background** универсальное и совмещает в себе все остальные характеристики фона, в том числе и  background-color. Всё свойства background-*, прописанные до  **background**, будут переопределны.

Comment: НО Ни одно значение не является обязательным, поэтому неиспользуемые можно опустить разве нет?

Comment: Я не использую свойство background-color в универсальном свойстве,оно у меня прописано отдельно, так почему же оно переопределяться?

Comment: @Maksim, по умолчанию устанавливается значение "transparent"

Comment: То есть если я не устанавливаю явно значения для универсального свойства, всем возможные значения  универсального свойства получают значения по умолчанию. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Maksim, честно скажу, что по поводу все - не знаю. Впервые касаюсь темы в таком ключе. Но то, что большинство - [это точно][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/bV4fk/1/

Answer (score 0):

работает последнее указанное свойство.

если вы хотите использовать два бекграунда, например цвет и полупразрачный png, то делайте так например:

```
background: #ccc, url(./../img.png);
```

Comment: рабатает последнее указанное свойство  если есть противоречие, а у меня его нет!